# How to associate FTP file name with Bing Ads catalog

Tags: java, bing-api

In Bing Ads Merchant center, you can create a feed and set "Input method" to "FTP". It'll then let you set the file name that will be uploaded to that catalog. See below
[image: Bing Ads UI]

From the API (which isn't supported in the Java SDK) you can create a catalog and set the catalog name but there doesn't seem to be any documented way of setting "FTP" as the input method and setting the filename. The Catalog resource docs I'm referring to is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/catalogs-resource

The code example provided for creating catalogs is on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/code-example-manage-catalogs

I've successfully done all the OAuth bits needed and created a catalog but when a file is uploaded via FTP, naturally there's a warning in the merchant center saying it couldn't assign the uploaded file to a catalog.

Does anyone know how to do this, what have I missed in the docs or otherwise?